# dovecot: sync client mails to server

Tags: email-server, dovecot

One of my mailservers stopped working and the mails seem to be lost. I have a copy of them (IMAP) on my smartphone, which unfortunately doesn't allow to export them.

My question is: if I set up a new mailserver with dovecot, can I configure the system to re-sync the mails from the smartphone to the server? (or, will they get deleted on the smartphone, too...)

Comment: no words about backups! :/